# I think it needs a refresh or update on click event, or something like

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm running python2.7, its native to linux mint17.

There is a funny thing happening here. The code throus no errers. When the 'next' button is clicked there is still no errors. But it does not do what I
would like.

It needs to update the value of K1 as a global variable and I don't think its doing this.  I think it needs to refresh or update on click event,  or something of the like.

When a refresh or update is put in and works I'll know if the return statements
are in fact returning the desired value. I have seen some return and updates, and believe they were for python3.x, this point was not defined. If you have
any ideas of how to do implement this using python2.7 I'm up for it. Please, any help you can provide would be very cool. Thank You all.

```
    root = Tk()

    input = open('path to text list', 'r')  
    L = input.read().split('\n')  

    k = 0  
    while 1:  
        if not L[k]: break  
        i = L[k+0].strip(), L[k+1].strip(), ..thru..L[k+9].strip()  
        k = k + 9  
        print i  

    k1 = 18        #    this value must be changed                     

    print k1, "line 23"             
    def next_pair(k1):  
        if k1: k1 = k1 + 9  
        print k1, "line 27"     
        return k1  

    print k1, "line 30"         

    def last_pair(k1):  
        if k1: k1 = k1 - 9  
        print k1, "line 34"     
        return k1  

    print k1, "line 37"        

    k1 = next_pair(k1)        #    and I hoped to           
    k1 = last_pair(k1)        #    do that here          

    imgxt1 = L[k1+0]  
    image1 = L[k1+1]  
    ..thru.. L[k1+9]  

    Terminal output from  
    print statements;  

    18 line 23  
    18 line 30  
    18 line 37  
    27 line 27  
    18 line 34  
    9 line 34  
    27 line 27  

    the command statements  
    in the button code;  

     command=last_pair(k1)).grid(row  
     command=next_pair(k1)).grid(row  

    class application code;  

    class Application(Frame):  
        def __init__(self, master=None):  
            Frame.__init__(self, master)  
            self.grid()  
            self.master.title("Image Processing Center")  
            for r in range(10):  
                self.master.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)  
            for c in range(8):  
                self.master.columnconfigure(c, weight=1)  

            master.geometry("1200x800")  
            master.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
```

Comment: You are assigning result of functions to the `command` argument of buttons.  Use `lambda`: `command=lambda: last_pair(k1)` and `command=lambda: next_pair(k1)`.

Comment: Thanky you, eyllanesc, I used lambda and it worked perfectly.